# I need only active website stores . Below code give all website

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
class Website extends Template
{

    public function getWebsites()
    {
        /* Use getWebsites(true) if you need to get websites with default */
        return $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    }
    public function getCurrentWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get active stores using following way:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param Context           $context           [description]
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {

        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', ['eq' => 1]);
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(['wb' => 'store_website'],
        "main_table.website_id = wb.website_id","wb.name");

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($collection->getData());
       exit();
    }
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need the data from table "store_website" (fied: Name --website Name) with Active store(active check from this table name "store")

Comment: Please check my updated answer, now you can get Website Name only of Active stores, Please accept answer if it'll working for you, so it'll helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code to get the stores by the current website,

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class YourFile extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory $storeFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->storeFactory = $storeFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getWebsiteStore()
    {
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $storeCollection = $this->storeFactory->create()->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId);
        return $storeCollection; 
    }
}
```

You can get the stores collection by using the below code in your PHTML.

```
$storeLocale = $block->getWebsiteStore();
```

Hope this will work for you.